# Instant App: is it a Web App?

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

Recently I just started to learn *Android Instant app*. As far I research, it make me feel that it behaves like a Web App, which used to replace mobile websites.

This may be a dumb question, but I want to figure out whether *Android Instant app* is a Web App or not. And, any difference between both of them ?

Answer (score 2):

**Android Instant Apps** allows Android users to run your apps instantly, without installation.

**Web apps or Now most used as Progressive Web Apps** are user experiences that have the reach of the web, and are: Reliable - Load instantly and never show the downasaur, even in uncertain network conditions

**Differenrences between Webapp and AndroidInstantApp:**

- **Web apps** have lack integration with some smartphone features like contacts,Bluetooth, flashlight etc. **AIAs** always have.
- **Web apps** can be crawled and discovered by search engines. While they don’t need to be developed as fully fledged apps, they still need to 
  be developed as web apps that meet Google’s standards.Whereas **AIAs** only need to be upgraded from the already existing
  native mobile app.

You can also got more info here:- [Android Instant Apps
Native Android apps, without the installation](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Instant Apps are Native applications.

The description says:

> **Native Android apps**, without the installation
>
> An evolution in app sharing and discovery, Android Instant Apps allows
>   Android users to run your apps instantly, without installation.
>   Android users experience what they love about apps—fast and beautiful
>   user interfaces, high performance, and great capabilities—with just a
>   tap.

You can see the official documentations from [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/index.html).

Answer (score -2):

A android instace app can be run without internet and ... not a web app :)

Comment: @Riddhi Why? True, this is a *one-line answer*. But it answers the question (even if not very extensively). Therefore, it actually ***is*** an answer.

Comment: I still can't understand why this answer is getting downvoted.